# handling OptimisticLockException

Tags: java

I am facing a strange issue.
I want to handle OptimisticLockException so that I can create a customized exception with appropriate error message which can help user to understand the issue.

I have written try-catch for it.But catch block is never entered. Maybe issue is that OptimisticLockException is actually thrown when transaction actually ends while my try-catch block is well before end of transaction, hence catch is never entered.This is my understanding.
How to handle such issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture, but if you *need* to catch this "as soon as possible", you can force a `EntityManager#flush()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29